# Export matching result from 2 variables

Tags: powershell, variables, compare, export, matching

I would like to export into a variable the matching values of two other one.

For example:

`$a` is

```
C:
D:
F:
G:
```

`$b` is

```
C:
G:
H:
```

The `$c` variable result would be

```
C:
G:
```

I don't find any function that allow to do this type of operation.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that any non-zero amount of research should not have turned up `Compare-Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `Compare-Object`. The below will work for your sample:

```
$c = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent).InputObject
```